# I am having trouble connecting to MySQL using Java and mysql connector/ J

Tags: java, mysql, database

I am trying to create a Java app using Java Swing. The swing GUI will have a series of radio buttons that will filter a "results" table in a new frame.

The contents of the results table are to come from a Mysql database, created on another machine using its localhost.

I have created a class that will establish a connection between the GUI that I've created with the MySQL database that my partner created. Here is my code:

```
package laptopicSelection;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class LaptopicGUI {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        getConnection();
        try{
            String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
            String url ="jdbc:mysql://1xx.xx.xxx.xxx:3306/Laptable?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false";
            String username = "root";
            String password = "xxxxxxxx";
            Class.forName(driver);
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,password);
            System.out.println("connected" + conn);
            return conn;
        }

            catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

I receive the following error:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException:
>   Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3
>   times. Giving up.

Again, the ip, username, and password are all given to me by the same person that created the mysql database on their machine.

I am attempting to connect to that database remotely, using Java on MY machine using the above code.

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: Are you able to connect using a regular client?

Comment: Meaning, through my command line in Windows for example? @shmosel

Comment: 1) *"I am trying to create a Java app using Java Swing."* Given this is already failing in a command line app. that includes no Swing GUI. it should be obvious this question should not have the [tag:swing] tag. 2) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow!

Comment: @JLotto yes. It looks like the problem is with the server/database, not your code